# How to put a number decimal (###,###,###.00) in a string value

Tags: java, android, numbers, decimal, number-formatting

**Hello all,** I would like my number (resultat) seems like this **###,###,###.00**. Into (resultat) in the String.valueOf from the below phrase of the below Java Code. Thanks for your answers.
result.setText("the rent is " + String.valueOf(resultat) + " currency");

```
package albencreation.realestateapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Rent extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText price = null;
    EditText profit = null;
    TextView result = null;
    Button envoyer = null;
    Button close = null;
    Button info = null;
    Button clear = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rent);

        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
        profit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profit);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        envoyer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttcalculate);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclose);
        info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttinfo);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclear);

        envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
        close.setOnClickListener(closeListener);
        info.setOnClickListener(infoListener);
        clear.setOnClickListener(clearListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener envoyerListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String p = price.getText().toString();
            String o = profit.getText().toString();

            float pValue;
            if (p.isEmpty()) {
                pValue = 0;
            } else {
                pValue = Float.valueOf(p);
            }
            float oValue;
            if (o.isEmpty()) {
                oValue = 0;
            } else {
                oValue = Float.valueOf(o);
            }

            float resultat = oValue * pValue / 100;
            result.setText("the rent is " + String.valueOf(resultat) + " currency");
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener infoListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, Inforent.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener clearListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            price.getText().clear();
            profit.getText().clear();
            String defaut = "result rent";
            result.setText(defaut);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DecimalFormat` to format the `string` as you like. For integer values use `#` and for decimal places use `0`

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00");
String resultString = formatter.format(resultat);

result.setText("the rent is " + resultString + " currency");
```

Comment: Sorry but that tells me into String resultat = formatter.format(resultat); the last word (resultat) is in red with Illegal self reference ?

Comment: check now! i missed that your variable is the same named! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
float f = YourValue;
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(f));
```

This code for show **Two Dights**  Hope will help you

Comment: there is a mistake in your answer.  `#.##` should be `#.00` for two digits

Comment: Thanks for your observation but The "#.##" means it will print the number with maximum two decimal places where as "#.00" means it will always display two decimal places

Comment: Like this is it possible ###,###,###.00, and what is it (f) ?

Comment: `float f`  f is your variable